# Create Macro and views in user space of SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

Hi I have been working in SAS so long and now I need to work on SQL Assistant. I have 2 queries. Appreciate if you can help.

1. I have a date value to be repeated all the way in the code. In SAS I would use

%Let mydateval='2018-10-26'

and resolve macro value by &mydateval through out the code. How can I get this done in SQL Assistant while working in Teradata.

2. What would be the code to save a view, macro, table, stored procedure under my userid in SQL Assistant. My Teradata production database doesn't allow me to create views, macros. Can you please help.

Just to give you a little more detail around what I see when I open SQL Assistant and login to Teradata using the connect button on the left.

The Database explorer panel has the following trees:

+645474774 (My Staff ID. Can use this data to save views and macros while working in Teradata. If yes, how to do it?)

+DBC (Not sure what's the purpose of this. It could be just another database)

+GB_DWHL_SAS_R15 (Note: This is the database that contains the views, which is used to pull data from Teradata)

Regards
DK

Comment: check whether you have rights to create.  link to check access is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492956/how-to-identify-all-rights-for-a-teradata-user. Most of the time access rights to create macros and stored procedure are restricted to certain roles only.

Comment: Shouldn't there in a personal workspace to do these. Just like SAS we can create a libname and store datasets in there.

Comment: you can create datasets in volatile or you may have create access for creating table in DB. if you see in SAS also we will be restricted to create stored procedure and other things. Did you check your access rights.